# Amazon web services and EC2 and Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04

Its a been along time since I am trying to configure ubuntu ec2 instance to run my java/j2ee based web app. I am a newbie/novice to ec2 and all other applications and services.

let me explain the complete scenario of my web app.

We are developing web app using java servlets and struts. Now I need to configure my server so that it has to run the app. I am aware I need to install tomcat6 along with apache web server and also we are using mysql5.1 database at the back end. I have created an instance of the ubuntu on ec2 since we are a start up and we using the micro instance. When ever i tried to install java6 on the ubuntu instance the server gets hanged up and later i realized that because of a bug and now I start the same instance changing the type to small from micro.

I read many documents of ubuntu and also aws but its not satisfying my needs. Kindly help me out if any one has already worked on aws ubuntu instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amazon micro instance struggles with JDK installation. Setup the server on a larger image size, then when you're finished, take a snapshot and run the snapshot on the micro instance. Note that Ubuntu only support 64-bit images on micro instance, don't create a 32-bit instance.

Comment: David, It support 32bit also I think.

Comment: Not for a micro instance, only 64.

Answer (score 1):

Try using some another AMI. There might be some bug in the AMI you are using. Can you please mention the AMI number?

Comment: my ami number is ami-6a3dcf03 if u can suggest me a better ami then it would be of great help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu Lucid, that might be a bug found at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ec2/+bug/634487

To fix see comment #13.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rodney I came across this bug and now I am trying to install ams ec2 api tools on ubuntu but I encountered an error saying package not found. I am running my instance in small type once I install jdk6 I ll shift to micro

Comment: You can get the list of Ubuntu AMI's at www.alestic.com